# Find all dates of particular row using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
id start end
1  2001  2005
2  2004  2007

output 
id date
1  2001
1  2002
1  2003
1  2004
1  2005
2  2004
2  2005
2  2006
2  2007

my logics
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'start': pd.date_range(row.start, row.end, freq='AS'),
               'id': row.id}, columns=['start', 'id']) 
           for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)

df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.id, pd.date_range(r.start, r.end, freq='AS')) for r in df.itertuples()]) .reset_index())
```

My data frame has minimum 300 000 rows so these are not the efficient solutions. Is there more efficient solution?

note: start and end are annual, monthly,daily....formats. I have given annual example.

Comment: If the data is sorted, you can try to find the first instance of `end+1` (eg. 2006 and 2008), then you can get the data till that index - 1

Comment: start and end are dates of yyyy format.you said is fine but for different ones like yyyymm format it will not get my ans

Comment: i have different formats

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wen can using `stack` with `groupby` `range`

```
df.set_index('id').stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : pd.Series(list(range(x.iloc[0],x.iloc[1]+1)))).reset_index()
Out[746]: 
   id  level_1     0
0   1        0  2001
1   1        1  2002
2   1        2  2003
3   1        3  2004
4   1        4  2005
5   2        0  2004
6   2        1  2005
7   2        2  2006
8   2        3  2007
```

Comment: it only works for yyyy this format.i have yyyymm and yymmdd formats also This solution doesnt work for me

Comment: @raam  `df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x : x.str[:4])`

Comment: can you explain what it do actually

Comment: @raam only get the year part

Comment: no i have to get data like this alsoid start end
1  201809 201812
id data
1 201809
1 201810
1 201811
1 201812

Comment: this for month data.i my logic i am using frequency as 'MS'